# Getting the count for parent node based on the count of it's children

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables with the following structure.

```
AD_TABLE -
              ID|NAME|CAT_ID|TYPE
               1| car | C0101|Sale
               2|bike | C0201|Want
CAT_TABLE -
              ID   |NAME          |PARENT|LEVEL
              C0100|Vehicle       |C0100 |    0
              C0101|Car           |C0100 |    1
              C0200|Bike/Scooters |C0100 |    1
              C0201|Bike          |C0200 |    2
              C0202|Scooter       |C0200 |    2
```

I need to get the ADs count of each category. And I am using the following query

```
SELECT     `CAT_TABLE`.`ID`,`CAT_TABLE`.`NAME`,`CAT_TABLE`.`LEVEL`,`CAT_TABLE`.`PARENT`,      COUNT(`AD_TABLE`.`ID`) 
    FROM       `CAT_TABLE` 
    LEFT JOIN  `AD_TABLE` 
    ON         `AD_TABLE`.`CAT_ID`=`CAT_TABLE`.`ID`
    AND        `AD_TABLE`.`TYPE`='0'
    WHERE      (`CAT_TABLE`.`ID`='C0100' OR `CAT_TABLE`.`PARENT`='C0100')
    GROUP BY   `CAT_TABLE`.`ID`
```

This gives Vehicle, Bikes/Scooters which are main categories a count of 0. I need these categories to get the count of there respective subcategories. Eg: Vehicles should be the total count of Cars + Bikes/Scooters and count of Bikes/Scooters should be the total of Bikes + Scooters. I am still studying advance SQL joins therefore any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a UNION to combine items from AD_TABLE with subcategories from CAT_TABLE

```
SELECT c.ID, c.NAME, c.LEVEL, c.PARENT, COUNT(a.ID)
FROM CAT_TABLE c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, CAT_ID
           FROM AD_TABLE
           WHERE TYPE = '0'
           UNION ALL
           SELECT ID, PARENT
           FROM CAT_TABLE
           WHERE LEVEL != 0) a
ON a.CAT_ID = c.ID
GROUP BY c.ID
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/773d3/11)

For more advice about managing hierarchical data in SQL, see [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/).

Note that my query only counts the immediate children of a category, not the descendant leaf nodes. Using the terminology from that page, your schema is the *Adjacency-List Model*, and it's difficult to process multiple levels in SQL -- it doesn't have loops or recursion. If you convert to the *Nested-Set Model*, he shows how to count all the terminal nodes with a simple query.

Comment: thanks this seems to work. But I have two questions. Instead of COUNT( * ) I am able to use COUNT(c.ID) which I checked in your fiddle & produced the same result. Because I've heard some saying ( * ) is more costly than using a single field. And I need these counts to be filtered by `AD_TABLE`.`TYPE`=0. Can you mention where to include that too..

Comment: `COUNT(x)` counts all the non-null values of `x`, so it has to examine each row. `COUNT(*)` just counts the rows, without checking for nullness.

Comment: I've added the `AD_TABLE.TYPE = 0` check. But your sample data doesn't have anything that matches that.

Comment: Your fiddle answer didn't have WHERE TYPE = '0', that why I was confused. sry. And I didn't notice it before but the result produces Scooter count as 1 which should be 0 because there are no ADs for the category Scooter

Comment: Changed it to `COUNT(a.ID)` so that categories with no children will count as 0. This will be NULL because of the left join.

Comment: I pasted your code to the same fiddle you shared. It shows bikes as 2 and vehicles as 2. which is a wrong result, and cars is shown as 0 when in fact it should be 1..

Comment: There's 1 car, but it has TYPE = Sale, not TYPE = 0, so it doesn't get counted.

Comment: I changed both the ADs TYPE as Sale and changed the where TYPE condition from 0 to Sale. Now the count of Bikes/Scooters is shown as 2 which in-fact should be 1

Comment: The count of Bikes/Scooters is 2 because there are 2 child sub-categories: Bikes and Scooters. I explained in the answer that my SQL counts immediate children, not leaves.